# Stripe not being called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Vue.js for my front end to call Stripe and create a token which then is sent to my backend. I have tested everything using plain HTML/JS and it all works fine, my issue comes in trying to use Vue.js  I think my issue might be in how I am binding the stripe public key. Below is my code, and I have zero output to speak of, I get just redriected to the same page but wth `?` at the end of the URL. Nothing else, console shows nothing and no error message or anything send to my back end.

**template code**

There is more but not related

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <card class='stripe-card col-md-8'
        :class='{ complete }'
        :stripe='stripeKey'
        :options='stripeOptions'
        @change='complete = $event.complete'
    />
    <button class='pay-with-stripe' @click='pay' :disabled='!complete'>Submit Payment Details</button>
   <br>
</div>
```

**script section with relavent added**

```
import { Card, createToken } from 'vue-stripe-elements-plus'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    components: { Card },
    data() {
        return {
            errorMessage: null,
            successMessage: null,
            complete: false,
            stripeKey: process.env.VUE_APP_STRIPE_PUB_KEY,
            stripeOptions: {
                // see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#element-options for details
                hidePostalCode: true
            },
            current: {
                stripe: {
                    plan: null,
                    last4: null
                }
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        pay () {
            createToken().then(result =>  {
                axios.post('/billing/updateCard', {
                token: result.token,
                })
                .then(res => {
                if(res.data.success == true) {
                    this.successMessage = res.data.message
                    console.log(res.data.message)
                }
                if(res.data.success == false) {
                    this.errorMessage = res.data.message // Display error message from server if an error exists
                }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                if(err) console.log(err)
                if(err) this.$router.push('/company/settings?success=false')
                })
            }); 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have checked that the API key is actually in the data value by doing `<p>{{ stripeKey }}</p>` and seeing the value show up. So yes the key is there and the key is valid (tested copy/paste into my HTML/JS test)

Answer (score 0):

```
created(){
   this.key=process.env.VUE_APP_STRIPE_KEY;
}
```

try this, i used this piece of code in my project and it worked... the issue maybe is that your key is not yet initialized when card us rendered idk. maybe key isnt issue at all. try this and let me know if works and we will debug it together.

Comment: Added that (changed this.key to my this.stripeKey instead) and same result of redirect to same URL with `?` I don't think it has to do with the way I am inputting they key into the script/template since outputting with `<p>` both before and after the card render works.

Comment: is token being created in your stripe account logs?

Comment: also add console.log and log result in .then of createToken

Comment: Nothing is being sent to the server, I submit the payment info (stripe's test info using test API keys), and it refreshes the page. Nothing else happens, the sending to the backend isn't happening at all, the API gateway nor the billing service report it happening. Yet I know axios is configured properly because I can send a request to a test endpoint from the same VUe file. Nothing is being created on the stripe side which is what makes me think it's an issue on the Vue side. Adding that console.log shows nothing in the chrome console

Comment: there is two possiabilities... either token is never created or you never invoke function on server. To see if token is being created you should go to your stripe account >developer section > logs.

Comment: Nothing is showing in the logs. Request shows in the netwrok tab as being sent so I know it's at least calling Stripe. Is there any way that the API key is not being bound properly to card element?

Comment: i dont know if it is required, but i also added script tag to html <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

Comment: to me all seems good about stripekey binding to card element idk... i can send you my implementation if you want and you can try to compare

Comment: I have that script tag in my index.html file, would love to compare with your implementation and see where the difference comes in.

Comment: Thanks, so I compared them and nothing major looks to be different. I did give up sorta and I just put my test public key directly into my template to see if that worked, sadly nope. So not a key issue, I then added console.log to before/adfter the createToken and both ran, added console.log to log the output of createToken, nothing ran. Also added a catch block to the createToken and nothing is there either